# How can I pass variables to a file printed from outside a bash script?

Tags: bash, variable, here-document

Assuming I have a variable `v="c d e f g"` and a file with the content:

```
line1
$v
line3
```

How can I make a bash script print this file with the content of the variable in line 2 as if I was using a here-document like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

v="c d e f g"

cat << EOF
line1
$v
line3
EOF
```

Output:

```
line1
c d e f g
line3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `envsubst` to parse the file and replace the variables that corresponds to environment variables (in `envsubst`'s environment):

```bash
$ v='c d e f g'
$ v=$v envsubst <file
line1
c d e f g
line3
```

Or, by exporting `v` first:

```bash
$ export v
$ envsubst <file
line1
c d e f g
line3
```

On my system, `envsubst` is distributed as part of the `gettext` package.

Comment: Or do an explicit sed replacement...

Comment: @keshlam Assuming you don't know the value of the variable (it may be user input, for example), that may be impossible.  If you use $v in the replacement text of a substitution comman in sed, it restricts the set of characters the variable can contain. It may , for example, not contain "&", or "\" followed by a digit, or the character that is used as delimiter in the substitution command. Depending on the sed implementation, you may even introduce a serious code injection vulnerability.

Comment: Granted, but (1) that isn't always a concern, (2) that ca